# conda: ResolvePackageNotFound python=3.1

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, spyder

I created a new environment called `geo` through

```
conda create --name geo
```

I want to install `spyder` in `geo` environment.

I tried

```
conda install spyder
```

But I got this error

```
(geo) C:\windows\system32>conda install spyder
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.

ResolvePackageNotFound:
  - python=3.1
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: As per duplicate: either update Conda to at least 4.11 or constrain the environment to at most `python=3.9`. Note that it is usually best to declare all packages at creation time, e.g., `conda create -n geo python=3.9 spyder geopandas` etc.